# How to parse a string of an object?

Tags: javascript, json, string, object

How to I parse `var string = "{email: godzilla@smash.com}"` into an object?

I've tried `var object = JSON.parse(string);` which returns an error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token e(…)
```

And `var object eval('(' + string + ')');` can't handle '@'.

Comment: Your string isn't valid JSON. What format are you using?

Comment: `JSON.parse` isn't working because the `email` key and the corresponding value need to be strings in order to be valid JSON. If you're just learning JSON, or don't quite have a full grasp on the syntax, try running it through [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/), it'll point out errors for you.

Comment: This would be saying that instead, string should look like:
`var string = "{'email': 'user@domain.com'}"` ?

Comment: @Wesley close, you need to use double quotes and escape them like this:  `var string = "{\"email\": \"user@domain.com\"}"`

Comment: @tcooc I am saving a string to a text file. Imagine the following variable being saved to a .txt doc.  `var text = JSON.stringify("{" + key + ": " + value + "}"); `

Comment: @Wesley if you're saving the string, why not let the `JSON` class object create the the JSON string for you with `JSON.stringify(object)`?

Answer (score 1):

Credit to @iam-decoder -- Check the comments to the initial question for more information.

Two solutions that successfully returned an object for me.

First -- Saving the value as a string with escape characters as follows:

`var string = "{\"email\": \"user@domain.com\"}"`

`var result = JSON.parse(string);`

Second -- Simply using JSON.stringify for the object instead of building a string, then parsing:

`var string = JSON.stringify(object);`
`var result = JSON.parse(string);`

Answer (score 0):

Your string cannot be converted into a JavaScript Object because you are using an invalid JSON string. Change

```
var string = "{email: godzilla@smash.com}";
```

to

```
var string = '{"email": "godzilla@smash.com"}';
```

or

```
var string = '{"email": "godzilla@smash.com"}';
```

Comment: this is still not valid JSON

Comment: Sorry about that, I've changed it.

Comment: There we go, much better!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this syntax with JSON

```
var obj = JSON.parse('{"email":"godzilla@smash.com"}');
```

or this one with Eval

```
var obj = eval('('+'{email:"godzilla@smash.com"}'+')');
```